# How to check if a string has more than 256 bytes?

Tags: c++, string, programming-languages

I have a "char []" output and its size is 256 bytes. I want to check if the string i am about to allocate to the output has more than 256 bytes in it. How can i check this? Does this mean the string cannot contain more than  256 characters??

Comment: A character is typically 8 bits, therefore a 256 byte string can hold 256 characters (255 if you include the NULL character at the end, which you should).

Comment: @GWW: I believe you meant to say that a character 8 bits, not 8 bytes. :-) (Although to be pedantic, a character isn't always 8 bits in every single case.)

Comment: A 256-bytes string can hold 256 (or 255) characters regardless of how many bits there are in a character :-) That's because ISO defines a byte as the same size as a character - it uses the term octet for a value of exactly 8 bits.

Comment: @paxdiablo: Right. I personally make the distinction since Unicode "characters" (or rather, code points) are 21-bits, not 8-bits. Encodings like UTF-8, UTF-16, etc. are a way to represent the 21-bit code points in a byte stream.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `strlen()` if you want to measure the length of any random string.

Nothing in your question would dictate the string cannot contain more than 8 characters.

If you want to provide a little more information, such as where the string is coming from and where it is stored, I may be able to provide additional suggestions.

Comment: Strictly speaking, `strlen()` depends on the fact that the strings are usually null-terminated. This will be true in 99.99% of the cases, but it's possible that one may receive a string that isn't null-terminated and its length will determined some other way. Proper documentation should be provided for this case, of course.

Comment: @In silico: if it's not null terminated then it's technically not a string but rather just a regular character array.

Comment: @paxdiablo: True, although old-style Pascal strings aren't null-terminated (they have a length byte at the beginning). Although I have personally never came across an old-style Pascal string, I'm sure they exist somewhere.

Comment: @In silico: I commented that I may be able to provide additional suggestions with some more information. All I have is that it's a C++ string. Gotta go with what I have.

Answer (score 0):

If it is an STL string object you are ouputting, then use the size() method to test the size.

Answer (score 0):

The length of char is 8-bit(one byte), isn't 32-bit(four bytes), so a "char []" which length is 256 can store 256 characters. A string "This" includes 5 characters, please don't forget the end-character "\0" of the string.